# Configure yahoo in outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, yahoo-mail

Hai Guys,

I tried to configure yahoomail in outlook 2007 it never configured,i even used used ypops the same error ... POP failed for user ...Could not connect to smtp server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Yahoo! Mail Plus?

From: [Do you have a subscription to Yahoo! Mail Plus?](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/mailplus/pop/pop-30.html#subscription)

> You must subscribe to the Yahoo! Mail Plus service or participate in a partner email service to get POP mail access through your email reader.

Comment: you can also be an AT&T internet subscriber to be able to use yahoo mail.

Answer (score 0):

You should have Yahoo Mail plus to configure your yahoo mail to outlook, as far ypops is concerned it was working fine a couple of months/yrs back, i think yahoo have worked out on that component as well....nowdays its not working for me as well